# UAG Direct Access - Exporting GPO to offline hosts

Tags: group-policy, microsoft-forefront-2010, direct-access

I'm probably missing  something here, but I couldn't find any reference to this.

I have a host that is using Direct Access from a remote location. We had to make changes on the server side and ofc, update the GPO.

Is there a way to manually push the policy to the client? It seems rather useless using a tool that requires you to be connected to the network in order to connect to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could take you sometime but it's fully possible.

Possible for two reason:

1. Since Windows 7 you can do a offline domain join.
2. Direct access does not install anything new. Nor in the server or the client. It's only a group policy that the wizard creates and that policy configure some special parameters of the TCP/IP Stack to get Direct Access working. But you, if you want, can implement the Direct Access manually. This is the [procedure on the server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee649214%28WS.10%29.aspx) and [this is on the client](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee649214%28WS.10%29.aspx).

So for answer your question what you have to do is [a offline domain join](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/offline-domain-join-djoin-step-by-step%28WS.10%29.aspx) and a [manually direct access configuration](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee649214%28WS.10%29.aspx) following the steps describe in the links of microsoft that i'm putting here. You can create a Bat to automate the process.

Regards.